# AndroidViewClient - How to get notified when the Android Virtual Device start process is completed?

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient, monkey

I use `AndroidViewClient` in order to use `MonkeyRunner` through `Python`. I need to start the `AVD` programmatically and **get notified when the `AVD` start process is completed**. How can I catch that event? The execution just does not reach the line after the `subprocess.run()` function.

Here is how I start my `AVD`:

```
subprocess.run('emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_26 -wipe-data', shell=True)
// the execution just does not reach this line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect that the AVD is ready using

```
adb wait-for-device
```

also, to start the emulator in the background you need [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).